# Can Regedit be used to grant admin privileges to a program or program key?

Tags: windows, administrator, privileges

I have several users who do not have administrative privileges using some proprietary banking software and MS Explorer to make bank deposits. The Proprietary software requires some administrative level privileges to do it's job. Is there a way to elevate the privilege level of the program, or program registry keys, without elevating the privilege level of the user, using regedit?

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to follow [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-administrator-mode-shortcuts-without-uac-prompts-in-windows-vista/) guide.

Essentially it will allow the program to run as admin without the UAC prompt.

The article is for Vista but can be applied to above versions of Windows I should think.

Comment: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: @and31415 I have come across some of links in the answer section that were unreachable.

Comment: Even though this answer is old. I would like to chime in. I have tried this solution and my program always starts up as a background process. It simply won't run as normal application starting by Task Scheduler even though system is logged into Administrator's account.